# TypeScript: Avoid require statements in compiled JavaScript

Tags: import, typescript, module, requirejs, commonjs

In my TypeScript code I am using a third-party library called [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) like so:

```
private logger: bunyan.Logger = bunyan.createLogger({name: "MyClass"});
```

Because TypeScript cannot resolve the variable `bunyan`, I do this to make the TypeScript compiler work:

```
import * as bunyan from "bunyan";
```

Unfortunately this causes the following JavaScript output:

```
var bunyan = require("bunyan");
```

The `require` statement will not work in the browser (when not using a [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) implementation), so I will receive: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Actually I don't need the `require` statement in my compiled JavaScript because there is a `bunyan.min.js` (browserified version) which I can use for the browser. But how can I avoid the bunyan import in my TypeScript code without having the TypeScript compiler complaining about an unknown reference?

I am using TypeScript 1.8 and this is my TypeScript compiler configuration:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `declare` to declare a module for `bunyan` with `Logger` and `createLogger`.

```
declare module bunyan {
    export interface Logger {
        info(message: string): any;
        warn(message: string): any;
    }

    export function createLogger(options: any): Logger;
};

class MyClass {
    private logger: bunyan.Logger = bunyan.createLogger({name: "MyClass"});
}
```

I would recommend using a typings declaration file like [the one found here](https://github.com/CorfuDB/corfudb-node-sequencer/blob/master/typings/bunyan/bunyan.d.ts) so you get the full benefit of TypeScript :)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. But if I am doing this I get `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'bunyan'`.

Comment: My mistake @BennyNeugebauer. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, James! I will try that out! Do I really need to declare every method of bunyan as interface method or can I make somehow use of it's `index.d.ts` file?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer You can use the index.d.ts file :) simply download it and then put this at the top of your .ts file `/// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />`

Comment: This I know. But do I still need to implement a fake `Logger` interface? Because the members of the `Logger` are already defined in the `index.d.ts` of `bunyan` and I was wondering if I can make use of it?

Comment: Nope, if you reference `index.d.ts` for `bunyan`, you shouldn't need to manually create the interface :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there are two things that come into play:

1. Package reference
2. Type declaration

**Explanation**

In my initial code I imported `bunyan` which helped the TypeScript compiler to find bunyan's declaration. With the assignment of `private logger: bunyan.Logger` I also forced type safety on my `logger` variable.

To get rid off the bunyan reference (to also get rid off the compiled `var bunyan = require("bunyan");` code) I needed to trick the compiler.

The TS compiler can be cheated by removing the `import` and telling TypeScript that there is something (`any`) out in the wild which is named `bunyan`. This can be done by writing:

`declare var bunyan: any;`

Because the TS compiler is tricked there is no way for it to guarantee type safety anymore, so the specific type from the `logger` variable needs to be removed and it's declaration must look like the following statement:

`private logger: any = bunyan.createLogger({name: "MyClass"});`

This bring us to the following solution:

**Before**

```
// Package reference
import * as bunyan from "bunyan"; 

// Type declaration
private logger: bunyan.Logger = bunyan.createLogger({name: "MyClass"});
```

**After**

```
// Package reference
declare var bunyan: any; 

// Type declaration
private logger: any = bunyan.createLogger({name: "MyClass"});
```

Thanks James Monger for making this clear to me.